# 100011 Sequence detector using 1 bit

Tags: sequence-detector

i made the 100011 sequence detector state diagram like this it's in link. Is it kinda true ? I am new in this topic. After this step I am going to do verilog implementation  [image: Tap here to see pic]

Comment: it's a least significant bit. My number is 35

Comment: I don't see any schematic, I only see a state diagram. And add extra information in the question, not as a comment below it.

Comment: Yes I mean is the state diagram correct ?

Comment: This is not a homework checking site.

Comment: Yes I know but, after this step I am going pass verilog coding which is why I've asked it.

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted one error (there might be more) :
in the state "got II" (in the top right), you have 2 arrows leaving for "x=0" and non for "x=1".
You need to remove the arrow "x=0" that goes back to start, and replace it with a "x=1" arrow going to the same state (ie from "got II" to "got II").

Then, excepted if it is pure homework, I'm not sure what use that diagram is.

If it is to be implemented in software, then just compute you number (using bitwise operators) and compare to the one you want to geet.

If it is to be implemented in hardware, there are also much easier solutions than to try to implement this state machine. For exemple a shift register for the bits, then a NXOR (output is 1 if inputs are equal) to compare each bit with its supposed value , and a 6 input and to check if all the bits are equal to the sequence. NB : there are plenty of other solutions, for example XOR+NOR ; AND or NOR + AND;

EDIT : you are speaking about verylog : if you aim for FPGA, then I would go for just a 5 bits shift register, and check if result equals to 100011

EDIT2 : the state "got 011" has also an error : you have 2 transitions for x=0, and non for x=1 (I let you find out by yourself which x=0 is wrong and where the x=1 transition should go to)

Comment: Hey thanks for answer it's not gotII it's got11 why should it go back to itself.

Comment: yes, your right, I sould have written got11.

Comment: If you get 111, then you can still use the 2 last ones for your sequence : so you stay in "get 11" stae.

For exemple, if you get 1000111 : you still have 1000111 in it, and the second 1 from the right can still be used

Comment: Hi sandro thanks for the answers I think I've found my mistakes which I have two of them. First one is got11 needs to go starting point because when it received 0 in terms against 1 it makes 01 so you can't mean it with 01 because my first 2 starting numbers 11 so that's why and also got011 x=1 condition must go to the got11 because when it takes 1 it makes 111 so it can still make 011 just going to got11. I believe that's the all mistakes.

Comment: Not sure I got your explanations (best would be if you update your post with your new diagram).
But if you are in "got 11", and you get à 0, then you got 011 (which is fine), so you should go to "got 011". It is when in state "got 11" you get a 1 that you have to loop back to "got 11". So there is no direct way from "got 11" to start

Comment: But you haven't really anwered what you want to do with that state machine. If as you hinted you want to go to verilog, then there are far easier and far more eficient ways than this state machine.